# Hosted form of web-based file transfer tools

Tags: file-transfer, web-applications

I'm looking for some software that will provide a service that resembles SendThisFile.com.  My users generally turn to services like these when they are trying to send files that exceed the mail servers limits (either our own, or the recepients).  I've offered to set up FTP accounts for users, but we find that some clients have a difficult time logging into an FTP site.

I could write something in PHP, but it feels a bit like I'd be reinventing the wheel.

What are other companies doing to transfer large volumes of data to clients or partners where the limitations of email are a restriction, and vpn isn't a possible solution?

Comment: I voted this question up because I am simply looking for a self-hosted solution similar to yousendit.com. So far I haven't had any luck hunting down a program like this. So I would appreciate if anyone can share their experience here.

Comment: Product and service recommendations, including file recon, are no longer on topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a lot of these over the years.  Generally when I am looking for a decent PHP script, I check out HotScripts, believe it or not.

They have a full section of scripts that seems to do what you want:
http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/file-manipulation/upload-systems/

One I can say I have used and works really nicely, is [Afian](http://www.afian.com).  It might be a little too full featured for your needs though.

Answer (score 1):

The best site to look for such tools is [**HotScripts**](http://www.hotscripts.com).

If you're looking for PHP solution, the categories you should check-out are:

- [PHP » Scripts & Programs » File Manipulation » Upload Systems](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/file-manipulation/upload-systems)
- [PHP » Scripts & Programs » File Manipulation » File Management](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/file-manipulation/file-management/)

Answer (score 0):

uploadthingy.com is a hosted solution that does exactly this for a monthly fee. I think data is saved to Amazon S3 so performance should be good. I haven't used them myself. Edit: Just to clarify, UploadThingy is a widget that you insert into your own website but the actual data is stored on S3.

If you want to host the files on your own server, the uploadify.com script looks really promising. However personally I don't want the hassle of maintaining customer's uploaded files myself.

I'm a new user so I'm not allowed to post these URLs as actual links - I could be spamming!