# What's your maximum email message size, and what do you do for bigger files?

Tags: email, exchange, outlook

As the subject says...  We're using Exchange 2007 and (mostly) Outlook 2003 and have a limit of 20MB.  For larger files, we have an ftp server that people inside can easily copy files to or from, and we have an account on that server that we can give out to outsiders to use to upload or download files.  The ftp server is an old NAS box that didn't work well, so it's got nothing else on it, the passwords get changed frequently and the files put on it are wiped every day.

I know there are services that can be used instead of having our own ftp server, I'm wondering which ones people have had good/bad experiences with.

Comment: A relevant question ... http://serverfault.com/questions/19795/hosted-form-of-web-based-file-transfer-tools

Comment: I'm still getting used to SF, should I change this to community wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We typically limit our emails to 10-15mb tops. Email clients weren't really intended to be used for large file transfers.

These 3 services provide **free** (or pay with additional options) large file transfer services. They are all relatively quick and won't jam up your email systems. They basically use a two step process. First you upload your file(s) via their web page, and then their server emails the intended recipient a link to the file so they can download the files(s) via their web browser. If you're sending it to multiple people and/or you don't remember their email addresses, send it to yourself. Then you can forward it using addresses from your email client.

**transferbigfiles.com** -- free, the simplest, allows multiple files, password protection, & multiple recipients

**yousendit.com** -- largest file transfer site, free & pay plans (more features), free still allows multiple files

**hotshare.net** -- free, one file at a time, additional tools - website embedded code, thumbnails, forum links, etc.

Comment: Here's another one for you: www.senduit.com

Answer (score 1):

We limit our total message size to 30MB.  The e-mail server can handle much larger, but we found that anything more than that and some users would have their mail client "lock up" on them while it downloaded the message.  Outlook 2003 over IMAP is notorious for appearing to lock up while it downloads the message if you have the preview window enabled.  30MB was a good trade-off between getting support calls for e-mail lockups and support calls for messages bouncing because they are too big.

For larger files, we have an FTP dropbox that some clients use to post files and then they send a link for others to go get them (in the format ftp://user:pass@ftp.example.com/somefile.txt).  These are, obviously, more technical than your average user.  Generally we see CAD drawings pass through that way.

Otherwise, we send them to a large file sending service such as [SendThisFile](http://www.sendthisfile.com/).  There are tons of them out there, some free, some not, with varying degrees of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with [YouSendIt](http://www.yousendit.com) in the past and they were okay.  The new kid on the block is [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com) and they are awesome.  Keep files for you to use among your personal machines or share with others.  Totally cross platform so I would give them a try first.

Answer (score 0):

I always limit to 5 MB. Some (free) e-mail adresses, have problems with receving large e-mails. For example, my provider in Belgium (telenet) give's out a mailbox of 50 MB. If I would sent an attachment via e-mail to an e-mail address from that provider, the system would reject it and even if I would sent it in different pieces, the mailbox would get full, very fast!

The best way is to use a website, rapidshare, dropbox, etc... for large files.

Answer (score 0):

All good answers WRT attachments, however another consideration is that e-mails larger then ~100k of text (excluding HTML) can make many clients have issues, larger then 1MB of text (eg, NetApp autosupport e-mails for large filers) and even mutt gets slow, everything else barely reads it, and hangs if you try to edit or reply to it.

Answer (score 0):

Its just 10mb to 15mb not more than but there a lot site offer ftp upto 150mb one time and it fast to rapidshare give same 100mb *